# How to structure one to many to many to many data structure Swift

Tags: ios, swift, class

I'm having a hard time figuring out how best to map out a data structure that takes a user, adds brands associated with that user, then adds items of clothing and the user's size (for that brand's item of closing, for that user).

```
class User {

     var name: String

     class Brands : User {

          var brandName: [String]

          class ItemAndSize : Brands {
               var itemAndSize: [String: Int]
          }

     }

}
```

Is there a better way to structure this in Swift?  I want to be able to store and call user.brandName.itemAndSize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best is probably not to create the relationship using inheritance. Relationship between people, objects and specs can be solved by mapping those in a table. In the example below, I separated 'item' from 'sizing'  because a dictionary will won't map a user to the brand and item/sizing unless you compose the key by concatenating the primary keys:

```
struct User {
    var id: Int
    var description: String
}

struct Brand {
    var id: Int
    var description: String
}

enum Sizing {
    case S, M, L, XL

    var description : String {
        switch self {
            case .S: return "S";
            case .M: return "M";
            case .L: return "L";
            case .XL: return "XL";
        }
    }
}

enum Clothing {
    case Pants, Shorts, Shirt, Jacket

    var description : String {
        switch self {
        case .Pants: return "Pants";
        case .Shorts: return "Shorts";
        case .Shirt: return "Shirt";
        case .Jacket: return "Jacket";
        }
    }
}

struct Mapping {
    var user: User
    var brand: Brand
    var item: Clothing
    var size: Sizing
}

let users = [User(id: 1, description: "Pierre"), User(id: 2, description: "Paul"), User(id: 3, description: "Jacques")]
let brands = [Brand(id: 1, description: "D&G"), Brand(id: 2, description: "Gucci"), Brand(id: 3, description: "Prada")]

let mappings = [Mapping(user: users[0], brand: brands[1], item: .Pants, size: .XL),
    Mapping(user: users[1], brand: brands[0], item: .Jacket, size: .S)]


for m in mappings {
    var s = ",".join([m.user.description, m.brand.description, m.item.description, m.size.description])
    println(s)
}
```